# After Updating Intel Rapid Storage Technology Software, Windows 10 won't boot

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, raid

After updating my Intel Rapid Storage Technology (IRST) software, My windows 10 desktop computer won't boot.

I'm using IRST to manage my RAID 1.

I can't access Safe Mode to undo the IRST software update, and I can't access my drives to retrieve my data.

In my BIOS, I'm using AHCI for RAID 1 and not RAID mode as I have in my old computer. My computer has been working great with AHCI mode for years until this problem.

Do you know of a way to access my drives to retrieve my data or a way to revert back to my old IRST software before the update?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Rich

Comment: What exactly did you update? The RST application only? Or drivers and/or drive firmware?

Comment: Hi, I updated the MSI motherboard Intel Rapid Storage Technology Driver Version 14.8.0.1042

Comment: Which of the three items I mentioned are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks Twisty Impersonator, I was referring to the IRST Driver

Comment: There were no restore points are dates available. I wish there were.